# Grails Controller data passed to view is null when accessed on view?

Tags: grails, controller, null, viewdata

I have an application that has some controllers, views and layouts. I am basically trying to pass some data from the Controller to the view. The view in question uses a layout called main.gsp in the layouts folder. So I used the code below in order to try and passed the data to the view:

```
def index = {

        String test = "Testing"
                println(test)
        render(view:"index", name: test)
    }
```

Then on the view it looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
</head>

<body>

        <h1>${name}</h1>
.......
```

Then when I run the application I can see the print data is fine however there is no data being passed to the view, is this because there is a layout being used? if so how to I get round this? Do I access a meta object instead? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def index = {
    String test = "Testing"
    println(test)
    [name: test]
}
```

This will render your `index` view by convention.

From your controller you have to pass a the `model` (map) to your view.

Now you could use the elements of the returned map within your view:

```
<h1>${name}</h1>
```

See the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Controllers/render.html) for further informations.

Comment: Thanks, I finally tracked the issue to the fact that I was passing the data to the view inside an If statement and for some reason this does not work :S

Answer (score 1):

The example from aiolos is correct, but when you really need to use the method render() with some data in model, you have to call it tis way:

```
render( view:'index', model: [ 'name':test ] )
```